# Unable to sync the gradle for firebase in android

Tags: android, firebase

I am using firebase sdk in android in which i am getting an  error as unable to load class 'com.google.Gson.JsonObject'.Even i have changed the jdk from 1.7 to 1.8 but it didn't works.Anyone knows why it is not synchronized.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "nidhinkumar.firebaseexample"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),   'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}   }
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0-alpha1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.2.1'
}   apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Error:

```
Error:Unable to load class 'com.google.gson.JsonObject'.
Possible causes for this unexpected error include:<ul><li>Gradle's  dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)   <a href="syncProject">  Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)</a></li><li>The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.<a href="stopGradleDaemons">Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)</a></li></ul>In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.
```

Answer (score 1):

[image]
i have also gone through same problem but after updating this repository it will work 
just update the tick marked file to latest then it will work

Comment: even i have updated to the latest version but still i am getting the same error

Comment: open build then clean project and then restart it and you can do one thing that is upgrade your gradle

Answer (score 0):

Add the following block inside your build.gradle,

```
 //Add the following block
packagingOptions{
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'

}
```

And in your dependencies add this one,

```
//Adding Firebase
compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.4.0'
```